# Clarifications regarding partitions and solution architecture in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am a beginner in Kafka. I need to implement it in my project.

We can expect some 200k records in the mysql user table. I have to track User events like User Creation, User Address updation, User Email address updation etc....

I have to integrate Kafka producer here. The important requirement is we have to maintain the ordering of events.

I need 2 clarifications:

1. Is it to good to have one topic called Users with multiple partions based on the User Ids (Odd Number of UserIds in Partition1 and Even Number of Users in Partition
   2). The idea of having more partitions is to make the solution more scalable.
2. How many Kafka brokers we can have in Acceptance and Development environment to make this an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka can easily hold 200k records in a single partition, but the number isn't really what matters, it's the size of each database record in Kafka that should be tracked. Additionally, storing the data in Avro, for example, would take less space than text or JSON.

I would suggest more than two partitions (using modulo. for example, with `user_id % 10`, or even `100`) and at least 3 brokers to have a highly available topic since partitions can be replicated across brokers. More brokers would result in more throughput, though.

If you want to track mysql changes, you can use the Debezium Kafka Connector rather than write any Kafka code yourself